# Proving that a nondecreasing sequence that converges always lies below the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If $a_n$ is nondecreasing and converging to $L$, then $a_n\leq L$ for all $n$.

It is reversing the proof of the bounded sum test...

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "It is reversing the proof of the bounded sum test..."?  Suggestions: Draw a picture, and think about the contrapositive.  If there exists $k$ such that $a_k>L$, is there a neighborhood of $L$ that excludes the rest of the terms of the sequence?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [bounded-variation] or with partial fractions

Comment: To be completely honest I'm clueless. My professor just stated this and he just said to look at the bounded sum test and its proof...oh, I'm new so I just picked any tags, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT** Assume there exists a $m$ such that $a_m > L$, what can you then say about $\lim_{m \to \infty} a_m$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that some $a_n>L$. Then $$\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=L<a_n\le a_{n+1}\le a_{n+2}\le\ldots\;;$$ do you see a problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Well, suppose there is an $n_0$ such that $a_{n_0} > L$.  Now choose $n > n_0$ large enough that 
$$ L - (a_{n_0} - L) < a_n < L + (a_{n_0} - L) $$
and note that the second inequality violates the non-decreasing assumption.